# C# checking for undefined variable received via querystring from JQuery/Ajax call

Tags: c#

There are many questions discussing this topic with ref to Javascript; but I  could not get any with ref to C#.

Both the 'String........' statements below return `false`.

```
     // foll querystring value from JQuery/Ajax call
     var  thisfieldvalue = Request.QueryString["fieldvalue"];

     bool boola = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thisfieldvalue );
     bool boolb = String.IsNullOrEmpty(thisfieldvalue );
```

What is the best way to check for Undefined string variable in C#?

Note:
I get 'Undefined variable' values occasionally, via  the JQuery/Ajax calls with the 'querystring'; and it ends up in the C# variable when I use the statement

var  thisfieldvalue = Request.QueryString["fieldvalue"];

and the 'thisfieldvalue' variable passes both the 'String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace' as well as the 'String.IsNullOrEmpty' checks....

Note 2: I have edited the question again to make my question clearer... I am sorry that earlier it was not that clear....

Comment: There's no such thing as an "undefined var" in c#

Comment: the compiler cause your code will not compile

Comment: And that wont compile: http://rextester.com/TJER37341 
Plus if you change it around a bit to compile, it returns true for both - not false: http://rextester.com/OTGKOT41237

Comment: this code wont compile

Comment: I have added a note above explaining how I am getting this undefined value.....

Comment: Based on most of the answers I suppose it has to be checked at the Javascript code prior to the JQuery/Ajax calls....

Comment: I appreciate C# may not compile but once the undefined-var gets into the runtime C# variable, it creates an issue....

Answer (score 1):

you could use either

```
 string Undefined_var = "[value to test goes here]";  //note that string must be assigned before it is used
 bool boola = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Undefined_var);

 //or     

 bool boolb = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Undefined_var);
```

Difference being that `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` will check everything that `IsNullOrEmpty` does, plus the case when Undefined_var consists of only white space.  But since a string consisting of only white space characters is not technically undefined, I would go with `IsNullOrEmpty` of the two.

But do note that since `string` is a reference type, the default value is `null`; so if you wanted to narrow down a step farther to eliminate the test for an empty string, you could do something like this-

```
 string Undefined_var = null;
 bool boola = Undefined_var == null;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no "undefined" string variables in C#.

String is a reference type, therefore if you don't define a value, it's default value is `null`.

There is no difference between a string not set to a value (default value `null`) and a string explicitely set to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013 your code doesn't even compile. The first check gets flagged as `use of unassigned local variable`.

As C# is a strongly typed language, use it to your advantage, set the value explicitly:

```
 string Undefined_var = null;
 bool boola = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Undefined_var);
 bool boolb = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Undefined_var);
```

Then you will get two `true` values.

Answer (score 0):

It question is not applicable to C# because C#  does not allows a non-defined local variables. Members of classes are initialized by a member's default value (for reference types - initialized by null).

Comment: @Ratna, all are correct. Here (rextester.com/TJER37341) you get error message due to unassigned local value.  Here (rextester.com/OTGKOT41237) you gets default value for unassigned member of class. Because the member-variable are the String (reference type), it  member-variable are initialized by null.

Answer (score 0):

> if (Request.QueryString["fieldvalue"] == "undefined")

It's a string, it will come across literally as a string.

If it is 5 it's a string of 5

If it is not there it's a string of undefined